# How can you return multiple variables defined and initiated in a function in python?

Tags: python, function, return

so my code looks like this:

```
def parse(info):
    """
    'info' is a list made out of data received (info = list(data)). Examples are as follows:
    ['NEWGAME', '1', 'testbot', 'testbot', '100', '200', '2', '1', '10000.00000']
    ['NEWHAND', '1', '0', '4c', '5d', '0', '0', '0', '10000.00000']
    ['GETACTION', '3', '0', '2', 'POST:testbot:1,POST:testbot:2', '3', 'FOLD,CALL,RAISE:4', '10000.0']
    ['HANDOVER', '0', '0', '0', '3', 'FOLD:bot3001,FOLD:testbot,WIN:testbot:3', '9999.9506']
    """
    phase = info[0]   # setting board cards to 0
    boardCard1 = 0    # 0 means no card
    boardCard2 = 0
    boardCard3 = 0
    boardCard4 = 0
    boardCard5 = 0
    if phase == "NEWGAME":
        gameID = int(info[1])  # Game ID
        leftOpp = info[2]  # Left Opponent
        rightOpp = info[3]  # Right Opponent
        maxHands = int(info[4]) #Initializing number of hands that will be played
        maxStackSize = int(info[5]) # Stack size, also the maximum bet size
        bigBlind = int(info[6])
        smBlind = int(info[7])
        maxTime = float(info[8])  # Initiallizing milliseconds of time allocated for the game
        return (phase, gameID, leftOpp, rightOpp, maxHands, maxStackSize, bigBlind, smBlind, maxTime)
    if phase == "NEWHAND":
        handID = int(info[1]) # The hand number which we're currently at
        position = int(info[2]) # Possition, either 0, 1, or 2. 0 = dealer, 1 = smalll blind, 2 = big blind
        card1 = info[3]              # Card 1
        card1Rank = (list(info[3]))[0] # Rank of Card 1
        card1Suit = (list(info[3]))[1] # Suit of Card 1
        card2 = info[4]              # Card 2
        card2Rank = (list(info[4]))[0] # Rank of Card 2
        card2Suit = (list(info[4]))[1] # Suit of Card 2
        hand = [card1, card2]        # A list containing the 2 cards in your hand
        bankRoll = int(info[5])    # Your bank roll, total amount made (can be negative)
        leftOppBank = info[6]   # Left Opponent's bankroll
        rightOppBank = info[7]  # Right Opponent's bankroll
        timeLeft = float(info[8])  # Milliseconds of time allocated for the game
        boardPhase = "PREFLOP"     # Initializing boardPhase
        return(boardPhase, phase, handID, position, card1, card1Rank, card1Suit, card2, card2Rank, card2Suit, hand, bankRoll, leftOppBank, rightOppBank, timeLeft)
    elif phase == "GETACTION":
        potSize = int(info[1])
        numBoardCards = int(info[2]) # can be 0,3,4 or 5
        boardCardsPacket = 0    # 0 for none, 1 for present
        boardCards =[]
        if numBoardCards != 0:       
            boardCardsPacket = 1
            boardCards = (info[4]).split(",")   # info[4] looks like 'Th,Ad,Js,5h' and split(",") turns it into [Th, Ad, Js, 5h]
            boardCard1 = boardCards[0]
            boardCard2 = boardCards[1]
            boardCard3 = boardCards[2]
            try:
                boardCard4 = boardCards[3]
                try:
                    boardCard5 = boardCards[4]
                except:
                    pass
            except:
                pass
        numLastActions = int(info[3+boardCardsPacket])
        lastActions = []
        if numLastActions != 0:
            actionsString = info[4+boardCardsPacket] # a string of actions ex: POST:testbot:1,POST:testbot:2
            lastActions = actionsString.split(",")         # A list of the actions ex: ['POST:testbot:1','FOLD:testbot','WIN:testbot:3']
        for i, item in enumerate(actions):
            if "DEAL" in item.split(":"):
                boardPhase = item.split(":")[1]
        numLegalActions = int(info[5+boardCardsPacket])
        legalActions = (info[6+boardCardsPacket]).split(",") # List of Legal Actions, ex: ['FOLD', 'CALL', 'RAISE:4']
        minBet = "NULL"   # it will be NULL if BET is not a legal action.
        for i, item in enumerate(legalActions):
            if "BET" in item.split(":"):
                minBet = item.split(":")[1]
        minRaise = "NULL"
        for i, item in enumerate(legalActions):
            if "RAISE" in item.split(":"):
                minRaise = item.split(":")[1]        
        realLegalActions = []
        for item1 in legalActions:
            for item2 in item1.split(":"):    # this creates realLegalActions which will not include numbers, will look like ['FOLD','CALL', 'RAISE'], makes it easier to check if an action is in legalActions
                try:
                    int(item2)
                except:
                    realLegalActions.append(item2)       
        timeLeft = float(info[7+boardCardsPacket])
        try:                                             # If the boardPhase is still PREFLOP then there is no variable boardPhase to return, so we have an exception for that.
            return (realLegalActions, minBet, timeLeft, boardPhase, legalActions, numLegalActions, lastActions, numLastActions, boardCardsPacket,
                    boardCards, boardCard1, boardCard2, boardCard3, boardCard4, boardCard5, potSize, numBoardCards, minRaise)
        except:
            return (realLegalActions, minBet, timeLeft, legalActions, numLegalActions, lastActions, numLastActions, boardCardsPacket,
                    boardCards, boardCard1, boardCard2, boardCard3, boardCard4, boardCard5, potSize, numBoardCards, minRaise)
    elif info[0] == "HANDOVER":
        bankRoll = int(info[1])
        leftOppBank = int(info[2])
        rightOppBank = int(info[3])
        numLastAction = int(info[4])
        LastActions =[]
        if numLastAction!=0:
            LastActions = (info[5]).split(",")
        timeLeft = float(info[6])
        return(numLastAction, timeLeft, bankRoll, leftOppBank, rightOppBank, LastActions)
```

How can I use all the variables that I am returning? What would be the easiest way? Should I have created a class (I'm not too good at using classes but I will revisit my code if it's possible with classes)?

edit----
I just want to parse the strings and then return all the variables so I can use them in other classes and functions. This is the main function that is importing it:

```
import socket
import sys
import pokerParser
from time import time
import betMaster
import historian


if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(sys.argv[1])
    s = socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', int(sys.argv[1])))
    f_in = s.makefile()
    while 1:
        start = time() # converting from seconds to miliseconds
        data = f_in.readline()
        if not data:
            print "Gameover, engine disconnected"
            break
        info = data.split()
        pokerParser.parse(info)
        if phase == "HANDOVER":
            historian.lastActionInitiator(lastActions)
        if phase == "GETACTION":
            if (timeLeft/handsRemaining) < (maxTime*.90)/maxHands:
                output = "NULL" #Null is not a legalAction so it will be changed to CHECK or FOLD later.
                while (maxTime-(time()-startTimeelapsedTime)*1000)*.90/(handsRemaining-1): #This will set the cutoff time for a response at a time that will set the bot back on track time-wise.
                    #output = jonsModule.attribute()
            else:
                while (time()-startTime)*1000 < (maxTime*.90)/maxHands:
                    #output = jonsModule.attribute()  
            #if output.split(":")[0] not in realLegalActions and "CHECK" in realLegalActions:
                #output = "CHECK"
            #if output.split(":")[0] == "BET":
                #if output.split(":")[1] < minBet:
                    #output = "CHECK"
            #if output.split(":")[0] == "RAISE":
                #if output.split(":")[1] < minRaise:
                    #output = "CHECK"        
            #elif output not in legalActions and "CHECK" not in legalActions:
                    #output = "FOLD"
            #s.send(output)
    s.close()

# commented = dummy code for now
```

Comment: That function looks like it should be multiple separate functions; it's doing way too much.

Comment: You should provide us a simple example of your problem, I don't think anyone is going to read through this messy code.

Comment: TL;DR. Please see http://sscce.org/ .

Comment: Yes! Use a class and classmethods. While there's no law saying you can't write python procedurally, you're missing out on oop functionality and really making the programming harder on yourself by doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Short Answer

You may return variables from Python methods in *any* manner that makes sense to you, or your intended purpose.  This may be a singular value, a tuple, a dictionary, a new class, or nothing at all - depending, of course, on your intention.

## Long Answer (which may be a CodeReview issue)

In a context such as this, you will run into an issue in which there are too many variables defined keeping track of different things.  It may be an old habit to use local-scope variables to keep track of stuff, but in Python, since you have the list (and you document what each position in the list represents somewhere), you could just use that explicitly instead.

Example:

```
if phase == "NEWGAME":
    return tuple([i for i in info[1:]]) # Returns everything in info except "NEWGAME"
```

It's a matter of what the full intention and scope of your code is.  I would ***strongly*** encourage that you sit down and [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code, so it is both clear in intent (not just to us, but to yourself), and each function is specific and well-defined in purpose.

Answer (score 2):

```
def test():
  return 1, 2, 3

a, b, c = test()  # a=1, b=2, c=3
```

Btw, you don't need to return tuples.

Comment: That doesn't help because depending on the string the number of variables and the names of the variables are different.

Comment: Sometimes I'm returning 5 variables, sometimes 6, and every time the variables I'm returning are different, will the only way be with classes? Or should I just not use a function?

Comment: If you return variable number of values than you definitely need returning a list. I'd also suggest returning a dict since it seems you return a kind of structure.

Btw, returning different set of values depending on input parameters is not an OOP style. This way maintaining and using of function is problematic. Consider writing several functions: one for every phase. It also makes sense to make a Parser class which will group these functions.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to return locals()

```
>>> def myfunction():
...    a = 1
...    b = 2
...    c = 3
...    return locals()
...
>>> print myfunction()
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return multiple values and a tuple won't work, you could instead return a dictionary:

```
{name1: value1, name2: value2, ...}
```

It then becomes easy to check if some variable was returned or not by using:

```
if name in returnvalues:
```

(This all is assuming you don't just reorganize your script completely, which looks to be a good idea)